# spring boot application context was not properly loaded if the yaml file wasn't application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

With following configuration, my test can read the properties from the yaml file correctly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ComponentScan({ "com.my.service" })
public class MyApplication {

}
```

Then I renamed the yaml file to my-application.yml, and changed the PropertySource to

```
@PropertySource("classpath:my-application.yml")
```

Tests are failed due to the null property value. The configuration class is as following:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
@Data
public class MyConfig {
    private String attr1;
}
```

The test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyConfigTest {

@Autowired
private MyConfig myConfig;

@Test
public void getMyConfigTest() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(myConfig.getAttr1());
}
```

Why spring boot can find the renamed yaml file, but it couldn't load the value correctly?

Comment: Can you post content of property file?

Answer (score 2):

[YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

It appears to work with @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml") because that's the default location and spring boot looks there regardless.

You may be able to use @ConfigurationProperties(location="claspath:my-application.yml") instead but it doesn't really achieve the same purpose (and I've never tried it myself).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW, I have tried @ConfigurationProperties(location="claspath:my-application.yml") , it doesn't work.